# Logging in chef recipes

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

As per chef documentation there is  a log resource available

```
log 'message' do
  message 'A message add to the log.'
  level :info
end
```

But this jsut prints the logs on the console during a chef client run. Can we not put these logs in a file at some location eg: /var/logs/chef ? If yes how can we differentiate between logs from various client runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log message gets put into the same place where all the other messages are going. You can provide `-L` or `--logfile` flag to `chef-client` to make it write to file.

```
chef-client -L /var/log/chef/client.log
```

Comment: Worth noting there's an option for the client.rb file also: `log_location`